# Text being cut off in TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout

I am having an issue with a certain layout in one of my apps in which text is not showing correctly. I have 2 TextViews in each TableRow, and in some cases, the 1st TextView's text is being cut off and/or not displayed at all. The right (2nd set) of TextViews are populated programatically. I just set `android:shrinkColumns="0"` and seems to have fixed the problem on smaller-screen devices (emulator).

Here is my layout file

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:fillViewport="true">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:shrinkColumns="0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/testHeader"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTest1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/test1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTest2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="text" />
    </TableRow>
    ...... Similar setup in the rest of my layout...
```

This looks fine on all of my test devices, but a user showed me a screenshot, and the whole 1st set of textviews in each TableRow are barely, if at all, visible. It got worse after shrinking column 0. What could be causing this whacky issue?

Comment: I don't know the reason of problem, but i suggest you to use LinearLayout instead of TableRow. You can also add android:layout_weight to specify a size ratio between your test TextView(s). In this way your TextView(s) will be shown as you want.

Comment: This is wrapped in a scrollview, and there are probably around 6 more tablerows below this. I use tablelayout for the columns, makes it look neat. If i used linearlayout with weights, it wont be columnized, and the 2nd textview in each row isnt a definite amount. Varies across devices

Comment: You set the table views width to match_parent - are you sure that the parent is as wide as you think it is? Try using fill_parent on that view alternatively. Check it with the hierarchyviewer. Also, have you played around with the stretchColumns attribute yet? I'd give that a try too.

Comment: Each TableRow is as wide as the device's screen, minus 16dp. Isn't fill_parent the identical, deprecated version of match_parent anyway? I will play around with stretchColumns, thanks for the replies.